# How can I display the run count as part of the `watch` output in a terminal?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, sh, watch

I'd like to see a run counter at the top of my `watch` output.

Ex: this command should print a count value which increments every 2 seconds, in addition to the output of my main command, which, in this case is just `echo "hello"` for the purposes of this demonstration:

```
export COUNT=0 && watch -n 2 'export COUNT=$((COUNT+1)); echo "Count = $COUNT" \
&& echo "hello"'
```

But, all it outputs is this, with the count always being 1 and never changing:

```
Count = 1
hello
```

How can I get this `Count` variable to increment every 2 seconds when `watch` runs the command?

Comment: A cross site dupe from Ubuntu SE [Incrementing a variable by watch command](https://askubuntu.com/q/1066882)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Inian for pointing this out in the comments. I've consulted [the cross-site duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/q/1066882), slightly modified it, and come up with this:

```
count=0; while sleep 2 ; do clear; echo "$((count++))"; echo "hello" ; done
```

Replace `echo "hello"` with the real command you want to run once every `sleep n` second now, and it works perfectly.

There's no need to use `watch` at all, and, as a matter of fact, no way to use `watch` in this way either unless you write the variable to a file rather than to RAM, which I'd like to avoid since that's unnecessary wear and tear write/erase cycles on a solid state drive (SSD).

---

Now I can run this command to repeatedly build my asciidoctor document so I can view it in a webpage, hitting only <kbd>F5</kbd> each time I make and save a change to view the updated HTML page.

```
count=0; while sleep 2 ; do clear; echo "$((count++))"; \
asciidoctor -D temp README.adoc ; done
```

Sample output:

> ```
> 96
> asciidoctor: ERROR: README.adoc: line 6: level 0 sections can only be used when doctype is book
> ```

---

### Final answer:

And, here's a slightly better version which prints `count = 2` instead of just `2`, and which also *runs first* and *then* sleeps, rather than sleeping first and then running:

```
count=1; while true ; do clear; echo "count = $((count++))"; \
asciidoctor -D temp README.adoc; sleep 2 ; done
```

...but, it looks like it's not just updating the file if it's changed, it's rewriting constantly, wearing down my disk anyway. So, I'd need to write a script and only run this if the source file has changed. Oh well...for the purposes of my original question, this answer is done.